# Выполнение скрипта по расписанию

Tags: php, платежные-терминалы, планирование

Давайте представим, что на сайте есть кнопка `"Нажми меня"`.
После ее нажатия где-то там на сервере запускается таймер, который через час (или в установленное время) запускает какой-нибудь скрипт, который (что-то делает), допустим, отправляет мне СМС.
Но рядом есть кнопка `"Не нажимай меня"`, которая сбрасывает этот таймер.

Короче говоря, мне нужен планировщик задач, который может управляться через php, через функции или класс. У меня система debian и php с mysql (где я бы хотел хранить данные о задачах, которых будет много).

Дорогие стаковерфловерцы, дайте, пожалуйста, дельный совет.. Буду очень благодарен.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

По первой кнопке пишем в базу время.
По второй стираем.
По крону раз в минуту запускаем скрипт, который лезет в базу, читает актуальные события, и выполняет их

Comment: Да, пожалуй, это самый достойный способ решения задачи...

Answer (score -1):

Возможно Cron? Он вполне себе нормально управляется через PHP, вроде как. http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=1153